# For C#, is it possible to specify type constraints in an instance declaration of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, types

I'd like to take two objects who have a shared hierarchy, and who both implement an interface, and put them both into one container, e.g. List, that normally takes a single type argument. I've used non-compiled code in this question, because I can't find a feature of C# that lets me do what I'm asking while compiling.

So, a setup such as:

```
public class DataObject
{
    int property;
}

public interface IWriteData
{
    void WriteData();
}

public class A : DataObject, IWriteData, IDoSomethingElseA
public class B : DataObject, IWriteData, IDoSomethingElseB
```

and code that does:

```
var x = new A();
var y = new B();
List<T> where T : (DataObject, IWriteData) mySharedContainer = new List<T>;
T.Add(x);
T.Add(y);
```

The List declaration line above doesn't work, but was the closest I could think of to get at what I'm aiming for. My hunch is that this isn't something currently able to be done, and that I need to either:

- define a shared class they can inherit from and that also implements the interface (which I'd rather not do in this case, as this isn't my code base and I'm trying to have as small a footprint as possible)
- do runtime typecasting, and lose the benefits of compile-time
  type-checking
- duplicate code by writing code that handles type A, and code that handles type B.

But, I'd be incredibly happy to find out otherwise. When thinking about it, I couldn't see any immediate reason that, theoretically, the compiler couldn't say at that line "okay, from now on I'll check everything added to this list has inherited from that class and implements these interfaces."

Thanks!

Comment: The question is: What do those classes have in common that they are handled by a single generic class?

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate a generic class without providing type arguments?

Comment: No, it's not possible. A `List Of T` is exactly that, a list of _one_ type of entity, not `List Of T1 Or T2`. From this point on I'm not really sure there's much to add as a meaningful answer. You listed yourself a few alternatives and tbh I'm struggling to understand the use case. If `DataObject` and `IWriteData` always go together they seem to be the same entity (what you called shared class). Am I missing something?

Comment: Jao - it's less a union type, e.g. "T1 or T2", but more a "T3" that forms from merging of both of those types - you need to have all the methods/properties of T1 and T2. As for whether you're missing something, the issue is that, unfortunately, this isn't my code base, and refactoring the code already there isn't an option. :(

Comment: @DennisKuypers: What they have in common is *ability to be converted to both DataObject and IWriteData*.

Comment: @EricLippert That I understood. It was more a question of "what is the list used for". Maybe one could apply a different technique to get around the issue that he has.

Comment: @DennisKuypers - the list's elements run through identical code paths that have methods called on them that are part of both DataObject and IWriteData, stripping out information from the objects and sticking that information into a dictionary after processing it in some form. Basically, I very easily could copy and paste the logic following that line, and set the type for one copy to "A" and the type for the other copy to "B" and the code will happily compile and do its thing. Currently, I've just gone with runtime typecasting.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, but why don't you define a `WriteDataObject` class that extends `DataObject` and implements `IWriteData` and derive both `A` and `B` classes from this class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The feature you want is called *intersection types*, and C# has very, very limited support for intersection types. In fact there is only one way to specify a type restriction like that, and it is this:

```
class C 
{
    public static void M<T>(T t) where T : DataObject, IWriteData 
    {
        List<T> myList = new List<T>() { t };
        // With this restriction we can make both these conversions:
        IEnumerable<DataObject> iedo = myList; // Legal
        IEnumerable<IWriteData> iewd = myList; // Legal 
    }
}
```

`T` is restricted to be only types that are in the *intersection* of the types that implement `IWriteData` and the types that extend `DataObject`.

But this doesn't solve the problem that you have. In this solution we can call `M<A>` or `M<B>` and get a list of `T` where `T` is definitely both `DataObject` and `IWriteData`.  But you have to *say* what `T` is. `T` can be `A`, or `B`, but `T` cannot be "either `A` or `B`". (And "either A or B" would be a *union type*.)

> When thinking about it, I couldn't see any immediate reason that, theoretically, the compiler couldn't say at that line "okay, from now on I'll check everything added to this list has inherited from that <s>object</s>class and implements these interfaces."

(*Objects* are instances of classes; classes extend classes, not objects.)

You are correct; there is no theoretical reason. There are languages that support union and intersection types; Hack, the language that I work on now, is such a language. TypeScript also supports this kind of typing. But C# is not one of them, sorry.

Comment: Given two classes that both implement DataObject and IWriteData...you can not mix them using this method...or can you? It only works for one of the classes at a time? Like..can you have a List<T> that accepts _both_ ClassA and ClassB at the same time?

Comment: @DennisKuypers: Re-read the sentence which says "T can be A, or B, but T cannot be *either A or B*."

Comment: Out of curiosity, are _union_ and _intersection_ synonyms for you? In the type system world I mean. You kinda differentiate them in your answer. I understand, for example, union types in TypeScript but they are pure syntax sugar right? At some point in the code flow you've to conditionally threat them differently depending on their type (JavaScript dynamism and weak-typing helps here).

Comment: @Joao: No, union and intersection are opposites. The union type `A|B` is the type restriction "either a type matching restriction A is acceptable or a type matching restriction B is acceptable". An intersection type `A&B` is the type restriction "only a type matching both restrictions A and B is acceptable".

Comment: So, to make sure I understand;

First, what I'm looking for is an 'intersection' type - which, googling seemed to agree with what I desired.

Second, even with that, I cannot somewhat 'anonymously' throw together some type for this scenario, because the C# compiler requires some type that is already defined to be specified in order to continue.

Is it possible to write a compiler so you shouldn't need to explicitly define an intersection type, and the compiler could create a scratch-interface or something of the like from type arguments, 'pretending' that fitting types implement that?

Comment: @MarshallConover: It certainly is possible to write such a compiler; as I mentioned before, I now work on a language called "Hack" which is a gradually typed variant of PHP. Hack infers union and intersection types based on flow analysis of expression types through a method; in fact there is no way to express an intersection or union type *explicitly* in source code; they can *only* be inferred by the compiler in the current version. We're considering adding manifest intersection and union type hints to the language syntax.

Comment: @MarshallConover: My colleagues work on a language with a similar type system called Flow; it is a gradually-typed flow-typed variant on JavaScript much as Hack is a variant on PHP.  They have some good documentation on union and intersection types, here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/

Comment: @EricLippert - Flow was actually what I saw when I searched intersection types. It's very interesting. I'm a bit envious of you and your colleagues, to be honest - it seems like very interesting work, though unfortunately not with languages I have great familiarity in. If you have any other suggestions on good places to read up on gradual typing and the sort of work being explored by your team and your coworker's, I'd appreciate a link - and thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

In C# you can only specify one type for a field, method, property, etc. That is why generics can not do this. Generics just compile down to separate classes/methods for every type combination you use.

You have to implement the interface in the class or inherit interfaces so that you only have to specify only one interface.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve however the statement

```
List<T> where T : (DataObject, IWriteData) mySharedContainer = new List<T>;
```

Is not possible for a few reasons. First off we cant specify inline generics, and if we could the `List<T>` type does not accept two type arguments.

However as I see it you could effectivly create another interface say

```
public interface ISharedObject
{
    int Property { get; set; }

    void WriteData();
}
```

Then you simply modify your classes as:

```
public class A : DataObject, IWriteData, ISharedObject, IDoSomethingElseA
{
    public void WriteData();
}

public class B : DataObject, IWriteData, ISharedObject, IDoSomethingElseB
{
    public void WriteData();
}
```

So the interface `ISharedObject` has both the `Property` and `WriteData()` signatures. `DataObject` implements the `Property` (note i changed it to a property as opposed to a field). Then the interface `IWriteData` defines the contract for the `WriteData` method. Therefore both will compile.

Now you have a single type argument and can call

```
var x = new A();
var y = new B();
var list = new List<ISharedObject>();
list.Add(x);
list.Add(y);
```

Appologies in advance if I have misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: He wants to put multiple constraints on the `where` clause but without inheriting interfaces/implementing the interface in the (abstract/parent) class.